# Angular http call header shows 200 response but response data shows html instead of json data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular9

I am using httpClient to make an http call to an api and display the items in an ngfor.  It seems to work cause I have three items being displayed in my list just as the three items being return from my api. However I can't seem to access the return json data.  When I look at network call in the network tab in chrome I see a 200 success, but the response is html. I am guessing I need to specify the json data type somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Here is my http call in my service:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.competitionUrl)
```

Here is how I am trying to consume the data in my component:

```
productlist = this.productdataservice.getProducts()
```

In my html:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let product of productlist | async; let i = index">
  <button ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start>
      <img src="../../assets/icon/favicon.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{product.productName}}</h2>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

My list displays three icons as it should because my api returns three products, but when I look at the network call from my angular front end page, I don't see the json data.

Comment: @mo-maat check in postman or any rest-client make sure you're receiving json response.

Comment: I just checked using postman and I am getting a json response.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you copy the response json and paste into [json parser] (http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/) check json is valid

Comment: Actually so going to back to my api, it does seem like I am not returning json type data even thought it is formatted that way in the site you suggested and on postman. I'm checking how to explicitly specify that on my api.

Comment: First check in your API endpoint . may be its not properly set for return JSON format

Comment: Ya. I've checked everything. I've even explicitly set the attribute `[Produces("application/json")]` but no luck. I'm using .net core 2.2.  I also tried this `options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));` per docs but filters is not a property.

Comment: I resolved my issue.  I was looking at the response instead of the preview tab of chrome's network tab so I thought it was showing a string instead of json.  It is actually returning json as I want it to so I'm all set.